# How to show logged in user info in all routes NodeJS

Tags: node.js

So this is my code that shows if `user session` exists and if it exists then it renders user info with the file so I can display the logged in user info there.

```
app.get('/', async(req, res) => {
    if(req.session.user && req.cookies.user_sid){
        let user = await User.findOne({username: req.session.user.username});
        res.render('index', {user});
    } else {
    res.render('index');
    }
});
```

But now I want to display user info and in another routes. So in my opinion it would be stupid to repeat again that if statement. What alternative could be there?

Comment: You could use `passportjs` in order to automate serializing/deserializing the user into a `req.user` object that you can access at any time in any express route.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to repeat that statement and make the DB call again. In the time between the first request and any subsequent requests, the user may have been logged out (such as by cookies expiring) or user data might have been changed in the database, so it's best to not cache the data and check every time.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

Add a user details middleware ,which checks if user details is available in session or not and then updates the session object if not available.This way you will avoid redundant calls to db across routes.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  if(req.session && req.session.userDetails === undefined){
   const userDetails = await User.findOne({username: req.session.user.username});
   req.session.userDetails = userDetails || undefined;

   //optional
   req.user = {};
   Object.assign(req.user, req.session.userDetails);
  }
  next()
})
```

You can pass the userDetails in all your routes with reference to `req.user` or `req.session.userDetails`, something like

```
app.get('/profile', async(req, res) => {
    res.render('profile', {user : req.user});
})
```

**Method 2**

You can also save the user details in session when the user successfully logs in and use the session reference in all routes, something like

```
app.post('/authenticate', async (req, res) => {
    const userDetails = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username, password: req.body.password });
    if (userDetails.length > 0) {
        //when authentication is successsful
        req.session.user = userDetails;
    }
});
```